# Accessing the same object across multiple projects in a VC solution

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a set of 30 variables that I need to be able to modify and use from within any of the 50 projects in my solution. Since, the variables happen to relate to the same entity, I would like to encapsulate them in a class. I plan to have only a single instance of the class. But I would like this instance to be accessible and modifiable from any of my 50 projects in the solution. Please tell me how.

Comment: A memory mapped file and a *lot* of careful programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static library project and use that to make your class.

As you build other apps (console projects i would guess) under project properties for the app, you should be able to add a reference to the library project.  That gets you your link.

There would also need to be a way for the app to get to your class header file.

One way to do it would be to put the path in the include.

```
#include "c:\somesolution\common_library\common_class.hpp"
```

Another way to do it, would be to add the path to the library to your VC++ Directories for the app project.

Comment: I dont think this solves the problem though. How do I use one object that I created in one project, inside another? I want to make the object even more widely visible than the global scope. I want that particular instance to be visible across the entire solution.
Your approach lets me create new instances of the same class in any project I want. But again, I dont want to create new instances, rather I want to work with only a single instance throughout the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Design the solution as a shared file. Then for a bit better performance you can map the file into shared memory.